# Reference request: Urbanik's work on random integrals and Orlicz spaces

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Several important papers on Lévy processes are referring to the following paper:

> K. Urbanik and WA Woyczynski, *A random integral and Orlicz spaces*,
>   Bulletin de l'Académie Polonaise des Sciences, Série des sciences
>   mathématiques, astronomiques et physiques, 15 (1967), p. 161-169

I couldn't find this reference in the traditional databases, either on the website of the journal. Is it possible to find it on the internet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paper request : “A random integral and Orlicz spaces” from K. Urbanick](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459824/paper-request-a-random-integral-and-orlicz-spaces-from-k-urbanick)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be available on the internet. I uploaded it here though:
http://dropcanvas.com/tpwrx

Comment: http://dropcanvas.com/23egf

Comment: Thank you. It expired again, though; would you mind reuploading? Thanks.

Comment: see https://mathoverflow.net/q/459824/11260