# Paper request : “A random integral and Orlicz spaces” from K. Urbanick

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, paper-request

I tried all my methods to find the paper :

“K. Urbanik and WA Woyczynski, A random integral and Orlicz spaces, Bulletin de l'Académie Polonaise des Sciences, Série des sciences mathématiques, astronomiques et physiques, 15 (1967), p. 161-169.”

It is not the first time this paper is requested here. However, the links for this paper always broke. If someone could please help me find this paper I would be extremely grateful!.

Comment: I agree with you, the material is extremely important for the theory of stochastic integration. Should not be left to be erased by the history.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't even know what is more viable, to contact some people from the university or from the Journal. I will try some of those optaions as a last try to get this paper.

Comment: Previous questions about this paper: [Reference request: Urbanik's work on random integrals and Orlicz spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/q/219542) and [Reference request: “A random integral and Orlicz spaces”](https://mathoverflow.net/q/435344)

Comment: Did you try a library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference request: Urbanik's work on random integrals and Orlicz spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219542/reference-request-urbaniks-work-on-random-integrals-and-orlicz-spaces)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here it is, not the best quality scan, but it should serve the purpose.

[image]

[Urbanik and Woyczynski (1967)](https://www.ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/Urbanik.pdf)

(the URL is also archived on the Wayback Machine, so it should last)

<sub>I notice that some older pdf viewers corrupt the image, no idea why, it renders fine on others.</sub>

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly!! Thank you so much for the insane help!.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a [copy of apparently better quality](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZhGoy0Z6azbolvz33JgQunQtG9FEVgYW66V).

Comment: That's amazing, thank you for sharing!